# How would you structure a flowchart/data flow diagram for an application that runs on a game engine?

Tags: event-programming, flowchart

I understand how you create flowcharts or data flow diagrams for simple linear based programming. But how do you design a flowchart for event based programming, like a game that runs on Unity3D? How would you structure it?

Comment: I would use a data flow diagram or class diagram instead of a flowchart.  Flowcharts are intended to encompass logical operations, so they would only apply to game engines in isolated cases, like decision operations.

You structure them just like you would for any other application.

Comment: You don't. Any non-trivial problem using flowcharts becomes quickly impossible to manage.

Comment: Here http://geekswithblogs.net/theArchitectsNapkin/archive/2011/03/19/flow-design-cheat-sheet-ndash-part-i-notation.aspx you find a description how one can use data flow diagrams for event based programming.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a data flow diagram or class diagram instead of a flowchart.  Flowcharts are intended to encompass logical operations, so they would only apply to game engines in isolated cases, like decision operations.

Comment: So how would I create a data flow diagram for it then? How would I structure it